# Alarm clock with auto flight mode

Tags: alarm, airplane-mode

I'm looking for an alarm clock which is able to turn off Airplane mode if I stop the alarm on wake up. (I turn on flight mode when I sleep.)

Do you know any alarm clock with this function?

Comment: you may be able to do what your want, in a way, with tasker. it wont "set off an alarm", but you should be able to trigger the airplane mode for a specific time frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [AutomateIt](http://www.appbrain.com/app/automateit/AutomateIt.mainPackage) to enable/disable airplane mode on a schedule.  This may be easier than finding a custom alarm clock.

Answer (score 1):

Gentle Alarm does that. At night, when you set the alarm, it goes into flight mode. When the alarm kicks off in the morning, it takes itself off flight mode.